# Allow files from an RPM package to be overwritten by another rpm package

Tags: linux, rpm, overwrite, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have an `RPM` I am making and this is in a very controlled environment so let's also assume it is safe to allow another `RPM` package to overwrite certain files contained from the original `RPM` package.

I know from experience if you try to install an `RPM` package that overwrites another `RPM` packages file's you get a warning that there is a conflict and the install fails (yes you can do some command line hacking but that is not ideal for the situation).

Is there any way through the original `RPM` packages `spec` file that you can specify these files are not part of the package they can be overwritten by another `RPM` package or is that just strictly prohibited from ever happening?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. They're part of it or not.

Comment: If you control building both, you could make one a subpackage of the other. Then they won't conflict any more. That's about the only time I've seen something like that work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way through the original RPM packages spec file that you can specify these files are not part of the package they can be overwritten by another RPM package or is that just strictly prohibited from ever happening?

You can use `%ghost` directive for this purpose.

http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html

Comment: This does the opposite of what was requested. The question was about including a file in the RPM but not owning it. The `%ghost` directive is about owning a file, but not including it in the RPM. The example given in the docs is a log file.
Still, that's a useful directive to know.